# Two containers one compose file network not working

Tags: docker, docker-compose

This should be something simple. I have a docker compose file that starts a DB2 container and another Java application container that does work against the database. The purpose of this stack is for solely to verify testing, the values in the database should not persist. But, I need the Java container to be able to make a JDBC connection to DB2. Right now, it's refusing, but I'm not sure why. I created a common network for both of them (I thought).

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  ssc-file-generator-db2-test:
    container_name: "ssc-file-generator-db2-test"
    image: ibmcom/db2:latest
    hostname: db2server
    privileged: true
    ports:
      - 50100:50000
      - 55100:55000
    networks:
      - back-tier
    restart: "no"
    volumes:
      - setup-sql:/setup-sql
      - db2-shell-scripts:/var/custom
      - host-dirs:/host-dirs
    env_file:
      - acceptance-run.environment
  ssc-file-generator:
    container_name: "ssc-file-generator_testing"
    image: "ssc-file-generator:latest"
    depends_on: ["ssc-file-generator-db2-test"]
    entrypoint: ["sh", "/ssc-file-generator/bin/wait-for-db2.sh"]
    env_file: ["acceptance-run.environment"]
    networks:
      - back-tier
    restart: "no"
    volumes:
      - setup-sql:/setup-sql
      - db2-shell-scripts:/var/custom
      - host-dirs:/host-dirs

networks:
  back-tier: {}
volumes:
  setup-sql:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      o: bind
      type: none
      device: ./setup-sql  
  db2-shell-scripts:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      o: bind
      type: none
      device: ./db2-shell-scripts
  host-dirs:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      o: bind
      type: none
      device: ./host-dirs
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add healthcheck to db service. To start ssc-file-generator after ssc-file-generator-db2-test successfully started and ready for connections.
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#depends_on

```
ssc-file-generator-db2-test:
  ...
  healthcheck:
    test: some command that checks db2 is working

ssc-file-generator:
  ...
  depends_on:
    ssc-file-generator-db2-test:
      condition: service_healthy
```

Comment: I'm not familar with the condition statement but the db2 test server creates a file to indicate the server is fully started and the data has been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The db in docker compose context should be available at the host:

ssc-file-generator-db2-test:50000
ssc-file-generator-db2-test:55000

Comment: I tried ping db2server and ping ssc-file-generator-db2-test from ssc-file-generator and both were reported as bad addresses. Just for grins, I got the IP address of the ssc-file-generator-db2-test container (172.31.0.2) and that didn't work either. At this point, I'd love a quick and easy solution.